# NLTK how to find full name instead of partial name

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

I am trying to indetify person from an text but it is splitting the text

```
>>> sentence = "Ram Kumar is best in this worls"
>>> print ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence)))
```

Output

```
(S
  (PERSON Ram/NNP)
  (PERSON Kumar/NNP)
  is/VBZ
  best/JJS
  in/IN
  this/DT
  worls/NN)
```

if you see there are 2 person

```
(PERSON Ram/NNP)
      (PERSON Kumar/NNP)
```

But **ram kumar** is what I expect as person in one line how to do this in `nltk` in python

Comment: If you really want to figure out the name. Use `Named Entity Recognition`.

Comment: As per my knowledge, there is no ready to use solution available for this. You can write your own solution by finding successive NNP tags and combining them. There are many challenges in above approach so you have to tackle them.